# Calculate random date between 2 given ones in C

Tags: c, date, random, time, struct

I have to calculate a date between a given date and now. I have tried the following piece of code which works mostly. However, it can give a date which is days or months ahead of the current date.
First it calculates the amount of years between now and the given input date.

The problem is that if that if for example the given date is `1 March 1990`, the difference in years will be `25`. But that means the random date can also be `1 March 2015 (1990 + 25)`, which is in the future (as seen from today). Adding `24` years will make the latest possible date `31 December 2014`, which is not close enough to today.

So somewhere I am stuck calculating the right amount of years. Does anyone know how to solve this properly?

PS tell me if more code is needed, but all input is done correctly and the right libraries have been included.

```
void random_func(struct tm *input_date, struct tm *random_date) {
 struct tm now;
 time_t date_now= time(NULL);
 now = *localtime(&date_now);

 int years_in_between;
 years_in_between = difftime(now.tm_year + 1900, input_date->tm_year);

 srand(time(0));

 random_date->tm_mday = (rand() % 31) + 1;
 random_date->tm_mon = (rand() % 12) + 1; 
 random_date->tm_year = input_date->tm_year + rand() % years_in_between; 

 tm_set_zero(random_date);
}

void tm_set_zero(struct tm *tmStruct) {
 tmStruct->tm_sec = 0;
 tmStruct->tm_min = 0;
 tmStruct->tm_hour = 0;
 tmStruct->tm_wday = 0;
 tmStruct->tm_yday = 0;
 tmStruct->tm_isdst = 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is it random or not, why is the example not "close enough" to today? Sounds like you need a more strict check which verifies the the month and day if the year is the same as today's.

Answer (score 1):

This is way too complicated.  Go easy on the task: calculate a unified date (something like the "seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01"), calculate the difference between both dates, get a random number (modulo the_difference), add it to the lower of both dates.

If you have to manage dates like the 21st of May 2000BC, it may become a challenge to create a function to unify the date, though.  But I guess some googling will reveal a good algorithm for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just treat the `time_t` as an integer, and calculate a random integer between the past and now, then convert to time. Something like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

time_t random_func(struct tm *input_date) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    time_t then = mktime(input_date);
    time_t diff = now - then;
    return then + time_t(diff * (double(rand()) / RAND_MAX));
    }

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    /* pick a date 1-year ago */
    time_t inp_t = time(NULL) - (86400*365);
    printf("inp_t %s", ctime(&inp_t));

    struct tm* inp_tm = localtime(&inp_t);
    time_t rnd_t = random_func(inp_tm);

    printf("random %s", ctime(&rnd_t));
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify by finding the time (in seconds) between the input data and now.  Scale that difference by `rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)` and apply the scaled difference to `input_date`.

```
void random_func(struct tm *input_date, struct tm *random_date) {
  // Convert time structure to a number
  time_t input_time = mktime(input_date);
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  // Return difference in seconds.
  double diff = difftime(now, input_time);
  *random_date = *input_date;
  diff *= rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0);
  // struct tm fields are not limited to the primary range
  random_date->tm_sec += (int) diff;
  // mktime restores fields to primary range
  mktime(random_date); 
}
```

OP's code `difftime(now.tm_year + 1900, input_date->tm_year)` is incorrect.  `difftime()` expects 2 `time_t` parameters.

C does not define `time_t` as an integer nor as the seconds since Jan 1, 1970 - although that is common practice.  This code does not depend on those 2 assumptions.